# Azure Database External Data Source between two azure accounts

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, firewall

We have two SQL database servers in two different AZURE accounts. 
We wish to add an External data source into Server2 from a database in Server1.
The data source gets added, but when trying to access the external table, we get:

```
Msg 46823, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Error retrieving data from one or more shards.  The underlying error message received was: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'.
```

It seems a firewall on server1 is not allowing connections. We already added "Allow Azure Services access", and even tried to add the IP of the server into the Firewall, but nothing works.

How do we make a connection between database servers in two different accounts ?